# Magento Payment Redirect Order

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

Is there any functionality in magento payment extention to stop the creation of an order before the success status from payment gateway is returned?

The Extension is designed as a payment redirect (with **getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl**) but really in the correct controller action, I do post from the action with params, to the gateway and return success if all OK, and return failure if not.

But the order is already created so I must cancel this order, but it should not create this order in the first place.

Maybe if I can design it as a gateway, I can use some payment method to do this?

I thought about the **validate** or **prepareSave** methods, but both of them are called twice - on accept payment method and on place order.

Also I thought about events - maybe I can use some event to do this post action and on failture just throw exception?

But I really think that in the payment methods, there has to be some standard functionality that I can use.

Comment: how about extending the _validate() method on Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote, and throw an error there so that it never gets to the "$transaction->save();" bit.

Comment: May be that's good idea. Will try this if no other solutions would be presented.

Comment: I think I'll use this solution because: 1. I can validate qote before sending my request, so I'll know that if service gives success order will be created too. 2. I have no need to create any controllers and do any redirects. Thanx

Comment: no problem, we used the same solution. I tried to format a proper example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about extending the _validate() method on Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote, and throw an error there so that it never gets to the "$transaction->save();" bit.

```
public function submitOrder()
    {
        $this->_deleteNominalItems();
        // do some check here
        $this->_validate();
        // End checks
        $quote = $this->_quote;
        $isVirtual = $quote->isVirtual();

        ........

        try {
            $transaction->save();
            $this->_inactivateQuote();
            Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_service_quote_submit_success', array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$quote));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            ...........
        }
        ...........
        return $order;
    }
```

Validate function looks like this:

```
protected function _validate()
{
    $helper = Mage::helper('sales');
    if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
        $address = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
        $addressValidation = $address->validate();
        if ($addressValidation !== true) {
            Mage::throwException(
                $helper->__('Please check shipping address information. %s', implode(' ', $addressValidation))
            );
        }
        $method= $address->getShippingMethod();
        $rate  = $address->getShippingRateByCode($method);
        if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual() && (!$method || !$rate)) {
            Mage::throwException($helper->__('Please specify a shipping method.'));
        }
    }

    $addressValidation = $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->validate();
    if ($addressValidation !== true) {
        Mage::throwException(
            $helper->__('Please check billing address information. %s', implode(' ', $addressValidation))
        );
    }

    if (!($this->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod())) {
        Mage::throwException($helper->__('Please select a valid payment method.'));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

The extended function can look like this:

```
    public function __construct(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote)
    {
        $this->_quote = $quote;
        parent::__construct($quote);
    }

protected function _validate()
    {
        // Code to test comes here
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('payment')->__('unsuccessfull.....'));
        // Code ends, now call parent

        return parent::_validate();        

    }
```

Comment: Really I have no need to use submitOrder, and the only thing I need is extend function _validate but I will fist do parent validation, then I'll send request and if error I'll create exception and then just return $this
By the way this is good solution and I'll use it

Comment: Hm - last night my head already works bad - just see to orderSubmit

Comment: I think I can observe event sales_model_service_quote_submit_before - so I'll try this and writeback my results later today

Comment: Submit order is only shown to show where the validate function is called. Let me know what worked for you.

Comment: working both variants as I tested, but using observe event is better practice, so I used it. I'll add new answer with sample for observe event

Answer (score 4):

This is quite a common issue during Payment Module development.
Magento offers two hooks for payment method classes to provide redirect URL's, one before the order is created, one after.

If a payment method model implements `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()` the customer will be redirected after the confirmation step of the one page checkout, the order entity will be created.

If a payment method model implements the `getCheckoutRedirectUrl()` method, the customer will be redirected after the payment step of the one page checkout, and **no order entity** is created.

This is not ideal, but thats what Magento offers out of the box.

Comment: Thanx for reply, but I think it would be more useful to work without redirects at all as we desided after [ShaunOReilly's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9187654/1043742) answer here. I'll try to use event sales_model_service_quote_submit_before and now starting to implement this. A little bit later I'll get my final solution here

Comment: I agree that it is nicer without the redirects. Only mentioned this because that is how Magento is built to cope with that. Redirects are very common because of PCI-DSS compliance. The correct place to implement a server side payment gateway transaction would be in the `authorize()` and `capture()` methods of the payment method model, not in an action controller abusing the `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()` method.

Comment: I know, but authorize and capture methods is not what I need. As I know - this methods called when you creating invoice, but not when you creating order. Or my be I wrong?

Comment: Is the request you are doing just some form of address and customer validation, or is it part of the payment process? Maybe I misunderstood your question. I believe you only want to create the order if the payment is successful. Is that correct?

Comment: Something like this. Here I do post request to some url with client data and getting response (we can say that this works like customer validation because if hash is good and all params setted + url is accessable we will get success result). And then if we get failture we throw exception.

Comment: So this is not part of the payment, but rather customer validation. In this case using an observer is fine. I might want to do the validation a little earlier, e.g. as soon as the information you are validating is available (shipping address, etc), directly after that step is submitted by the customer. That way he would get the appropriate error message right after he specified the data.

Comment: No - I said that that's this just like validation. Really what happens here - I send fields filled in payment form to Credit Service, they check them and if something wrong - they give me failture response, but if all OK - they save this customers data and start to process it (make call to customer for details etc.). So this information after posting it already stored in this service, and if I would send this information them on Payment Method validate - I will store this information many times. on validate I do my own validation of fields posted, but I can't sent it to CS

Comment: This should be part of the payment model then, in the method `authorize()`. But this is out of scope of this question. I assume they return a token so you don't have to store the CC information. The whole legal issue here is huge, so I'll back out of this now :)

Comment: `authorize()` method is not called when you creating order - it called when you create invoce, so this is not my solution.

Comment: And thanx for such long discussion

Answer (score 0):

As I said - giving sample that I used for this solution at final.

I prefered to observe event to do post request. Really if you'll use method presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9187654/1043742)
you will take the same effect, but I prefer to use event observer. So:

First add some data to **config.xml** to create event observer in **frontend** section

```
<events>
    <sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
        <observers>
            <lacpaycs>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>OS_LacPayCS_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>lacpaycs_payment_send</method>
            </lacpaycs>
        </observers>
    </sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
</events>
```

then we must create Observer class in *OS/LacPayCS/Mode/Observer.php*:

```
     class OS_LacPayCS_Model_Observer {

        protected $_code = 'lacpaycs';

        // Here some our additional functions

        /**
         * @param Varien_Object $observer
         */
        public function lacpaycs_payment_send(Varien_Object $observer)
        {
            /**
             * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
             * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote
             */
            $order = $observer->getOrder();
            $quote = $observer->getQuote();
            $payment = $order->getPayment();
            if ($payment->getMethodInstance()->getCode() != $this->_code) {
                return;
            }

            $helper = Mage::helper('lacpaycs');
            try {

                // Here we prepare data and sending request to gateway, and getting response

                if (!$this->_validateResponse($response)) {
                    Mage::throwException('Error '.$this->errorMsg);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::throwException($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```

So in two words what we doing here **$_code** is the same that in our payment model and with it we checking in observer if we catched event when customer using our payment method

All another code is simple, so I think it's no need to comment it